# How to properly bind datagrid and textboxes and only update the datagrid after clicking a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have WPF app and having trouble with binding. My UI looks like the image on the link. (My apologies for not embedding the image since I'm a new user and need to gain points in order to post image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1koN.jpg

Basically 1 Product can have many Pricing Details. The screen is for the Edit mode where the information is retrieved from the database (for the sake of this sample, I just hard coded the values). Selecting an item in the `datagrid` will load the information on its respective textboxes. This is currently working fine. The only thing that i would like to modify is the behavior when changing the value in  the textbox because the `datagrid` gets immediately updated. Would it be possible to only update the datagrid once the `EDIT` button is clicked? Note that any changes made in this point is not yet persisted in the database, it would only be persisted when the `UPDATE` button(on the top) is clicked.

Here's the snippet of the XAML file:

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductPrices, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductPrice}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat=\{0:N\}}" Header="Unit Price" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LowestPrice, StringFormat=\{0:N\}}" Header="Lowest Price" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EffectiveDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" Header="Effective Date" Width="150"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**TextBoxes**

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=ProductPrice.UnitPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, StringFormat=\{0:N\}}" Width="100" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=ProductPrice.LowestPrice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, StringFormat=\{0:N\}}" Width="100" />
<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=ProductPrice.EffectiveDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="100" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private Product _product;
    public Product Product
    {
        get { return _product; }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Product);
        }
    }

    private ProductPrice _productPrice;
    public ProductPrice ProductPrice
    {
        get { return _productPrice; }
        set
        {
            _productPrice = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ProductPrice);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ProductPrice> _productPrices;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductPrice> ProductPrices
    {
        get { return _productPrices; }
        set
        {
            _productPrices = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ProductPrices);
        }
    }
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` must be the culprit. But I still don't have an idea on how to solve this case. Is this achievable using `MVVM` approach?

I had uploaded the source code on [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=974337211B5F9E8B&id=974337211B5F9E8B!109)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Explicit UpdateSourceTrigger in your binding and then invoke UpdateSource manually when the button is clicked:

[XAML Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger when a Button.Click is fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317706/xaml-binding-updatesourcetrigger-when-a-button-click-is-fired)

If you want to make the process easier, define a BindingGroup for all your bindings and then just call UpdateSources on your BindingGroup when you click the button. You could implement the call to UpdateSources via a simple behavior or attached property.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I believe this method will require a code behind. Is there alternative using MVVM approach? If not, then I'll accept this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you could always create a special command or behavior that you attach in xaml which calls the UpdateSources on the BindingGroup...then no code behind is required.